# AWS me-central-1 region issues with aws provider 4.5

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am getting error when building EC2 instance

```
Error: region not found for name "me-central-1"
"aws_region" "current":
   1: data "aws_region" "current" {}

Error: region not found for name "me-central-1"
  50: data "aws_region" "this" {}
```

region is showing us that is enabled correctly

```
{
      "Endpoint": "ec2.me-central-1.amazonaws.com",
      "RegionName": "me-central-1",
      "OptInStatus": "opted-in"
    },
```

even if i add to backend or provider `skip_region_validation = true` the `aws_region` resource is still failing

any idea how we could fix this ?

Terraform version 0.13.7
aws provider 4.5.0

Comment: There were some updates in the provider version 4.55.0, so you might want to try with that first.

Comment: yes @MarkoE it looks better with version v4.56.0 but there are still some troubles, as i still had to add `skip_region_validation = true` to pass it

Comment: I guess you can open a bug report on [terraform-provider-aws repo](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws) for that.